# Struts2 checkbox value gets reset when page submit happens, the attribute is part of a list of checkboxes

Tags: jsp, google-chrome, struts2

Struts2 checkbox value gets reset when page
 redirect to the same struts action/refresh etc, the attribute is part of a list of checkboxes that gets filled based on the bean values. This is only happening in Chrome browser and not on all browsers. Note I am using model driven approach and the bean attribute that I am concerned is of type boolean , it gets reset to "false" even after using s: tag named attribute as an hidden/display none approach. Code below.

```
<s:iterator status="statusVal"  value="myBean">
   <s:checkbox name="myBean[%{#statusVal.index}].disableValueTracker"
      fieldValue="true" value="%{disableValueTracker}" 


     cssStyle="display:none;"/>

**Underneath where I actually set the disabled true.**

    <s:if test="disableValueTracker== true">
     <s:checkbox id="testing" name="myBean[%{#statusVal.index}].aTabVal" 
       fieldValue="%{#myList.myNumber}" disabled="true" />
   </s:if>
  <s:else>
      <s:checkbox id="testing" name="myBean
          [%{#statusVal.index}].aTabVal" fieldValue="true" 
        value="%{#myList.myNumber}" />
</s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Why they have the same value on all checkboxes?

Comment: actually this was just a demo of the actual code.. I have renamed few fields...coming back to my issue, I have a doubt that the value gets somewhere reset after the submit button is hit. Period.... Now, some other context starts... ... I faced a similar issue when i was passing value across different pages of the form when disabled elements were there, as in, a checked radio button that is disabled. later after much debugging i understood that disables attribute stop value prorogation, then, I had to manually enable the radio button and then  submit the form so that value gets to the backend..

Comment: You misunderstood how Struts2 checkboxes work. You said it doesn't work only with Chrome browser and it works in other browsers, isn't it?

Comment: Bingo. Yes that is right, this functionality is not working in Chrome. But for other browsers its working fine. What exactly I misunderstood/or did wrong could you plz explain.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by replacing the `<s:checkbox>` tag with `<s:hidden>`. As, `Roman C` explained that in Struts2 uses check box differently, so, I got rid of `<s:checkbox>` completely, which in the above case, I was using as a hidden field. I am still not sure why reset happens in chrome browser when `<s:checkbox>` is used as a pseudo hidden field, that is, using `display:none` (`display:none` passes value of the attribute internally to the back-end when form submit happens. Though `display:none` in the case of `textfields` works fine but looks like, `s:checkbox` works differently in `Struts2`). This `s:tag` element change from `s:checkbox` to `<s:hidden>` did the trick for me.

So, I replaced  -->(-)

```
 <s:checkbox name="myBean[%{#statusVal.index}].disableValueTracker"
          fieldValue="true" value="%{disableValueTracker}" 
        cssStyle="display:none;"/>
```

with ---> (+) `<s:hidden blah bla blah  />`